# Is there a way to animate a set position on H.map.DomMarker?

Tags: javascript, here-api

I am changing a marker's position every 15 seconds based on the position from another device (something similar to what UBER does).

So basically I am doing this:

```
    //this is the new position I get
    const posObj = { lat: lat, lng: lng };

    this.map.setCenter(posObj, true);
    this.truckMarker.setPosition(posObj);
```

The problem is that the change looks **abrupt**, I mean there is no transition or animation between the two positions.

I added a css transition to the marker

```
transition: transform 1s linear;
```

and it is working better but I am still having troubles to animate the set center function.

*BTW, I am using Ionic 3, Angular 5*

Thanks in advance for you help!

Answer (score 0):

Please check below route matching api between two locations or more than for a smooth transition.

https://developer.here.com/documentation/route-match/topics/quick-start-gps-trace-route.html

Requesting a route matching between two locations, you will get a route including many lat&lon along roads.
From the route result you can set lat&lon values.
I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your response but I think it is too much expensive to make a request to the server to have a route every 15 seconds, because I already have point A and Point B and they are relatively very close each other, so I just need to animate the marker and the map position.

Answer (score 0):

You can use requestAnimationFrame in Angular for frame by frame animation and modify the marker in it.

```
private animate() {
   
    requestAnimationFrame(() => this.animate());
  }
```

Comment: Tags are javascript, yet you answered mentioning Angular and your code literally shows nothing. Please do include some proper code.